# qemu makefile error cannot find library that I know is there

Tags: linux, makefile, libraries, qemu

when I run make for qemu everything goes fine until:

`LINK  ppc-softmmu/qemu-system-ppc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latk-1.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lselinux
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lharfbuzz
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.a(CrGlCur.o): In function open_library':
(.text+0x32): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lffi
../os-posix.o: In function change_process_uid':
/mnt/qemu-latest/qemu/os-posix.c:173: warning: Using 'initgroups' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking`

etc.
and it fails with an error.

I thought maybe the libraries are missing so I tried ld -latk-1.0 -verbose
on latk-1.0 and also the other libraries, which gave me:

`...attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.a failed
attempt to open //lib64/libatk-1.0.so failed
attempt to open //lib64/libatk-1.0.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so succeeded
-latk-1.0 (//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 needed by //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so
found libgobject-2.0.so.0 at //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
libglib-2.0.so.0 needed by //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so
found libglib-2.0.so.0 at //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
libc.so.6 needed by //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so
found libc.so.6 at //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
libffi.so.6 needed by //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
found libffi.so.6 at //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6
libpcre.so.3 needed by //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
found libpcre.so.3 at //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3
libpthread.so.0 needed by //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
found libpthread.so.0 at //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 needed by //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
found ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 at //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address`

it does this for all the other libraries it supposedly can't find. I can't figure out why make is not finding these libraries, is it because it's only looking for static libraries? If that's the case how do I get the static libraries for these? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi nevermind I fixed it.

Problem is the project I'm working on has gone through the hands of many people, and the documentation is sparse, so I've been playing detective trying to get the thing working again.

Just had to re ./configure it and take out the --static option